# OfType preforms cast instead of filter

Tags: c#, ienumerable, oftype

Let's say in my database I have 2 classes: Class FooBar and Class BarFoo. I perform a query on  my database which returns class FooBos which contains a list of FooBar **BUT** the list can contain instances of BarFoo(don't ask me why , this how i got the database and i can't edit it).

Anyway to build my Domain object I do a check to see which class is which using following code

```
if(FooBos.FooBars.OfType<BarFoo>().Count() != 0)
  //Do things for FooBar here
else
  //Do Things for BarFoo here
```

So the problem is after the OfType the entire list is of the Type BarFoo and i can't seem to figure out why.

Anyone knows why this happens ?

Comment: `OfType` is used to iterate over a list and select only the types that can be cast to the target type, the rest are simply skipped. Seeing if the count is not zero is no indicator that the entire list contains *only* that type. It also seems like your if statement is backwards, well, at least your comments are.

Comment: I suggest you use clearer names than Bar and Foo, this is confusing. Also OfType<T> filters out only elements of the given type, thus getting only items of `BarFoo` seems logical to me.

Comment: @Abbas yes i know that but the casting happens on the entire list even instances of FooBar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `OfType<>` is employed whenever an inheritance relation exists. In your case, I suspect that FooBar is a child of BarFoo.

If this is the case then it means all of your objects in the list is either inherit BarFoo or they are just BarFoo objects; so `OfType<BarFoo>` returns all objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind iterating twice (using Linq), you can use two separate statements:

```
foreach (BarFoo barfoo in FooBos.FooBars.OfType<BarFoo>()
    // Do something with barfoo

foreach (FooBar foobar in FooBos.Foobars.OfType<FooBar>()
    // Do something with foobar
```

Otherwise you'll have to do it in a single loop the long way:

```
foreach (var entry in FooBos.FooBars)
{
    BarFoo barfoo = entry as BarFoo;

    if (barfoo != null)
    {
        // Do something with barfoo
    }
    else
    {
        FooBar foobar = entry as FooBar;

        if (foobar != null)
        {
            // Do something with foobar
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing that now to avoid the casting. Well sort of the same but daryal is right it's because there is inheritance between the classes